# Project Euler #1

Tags: programming-challenge, functional-programming, clojure

I'm learning Clojure and solved Project Euler #1, I'd like to have my code reviewed on all aspects and have one specific question. This is also my first Functional Programming language, I have however used some form of FP in Java and Python before.

**Task: Multiples of 3 and 5**

> If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
>
> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

**My solution**

```
 (ns euler)

 (defn is-divisible-by?
   [x divisor]
   (zero? (mod x divisor)))

(->> (range 1000)
     (filter #(or (is-divisible-by? % 3) (is-divisible-by? % 5)))
     (reduce +)
     (println))
```

My additional question is whether the filter part can be written more succintly as I'm duplicating code right now while all I need to actually to is dos ome operation on `3` and `5`.

Answer (score 2):

Good to extract the method `is-divisible-by?`. Ending with a question mark indicates a predicate, so `is-` prefix is not necessary. I think it is somewhat more readable if the divisor comes before the value, but that might be personal preference.

```
(defn divisible-by?
  [divisor x]
  (zero? (mod x divisor)))
```

Furthermore, if you provide a conditional in the `fn` to `reduce` you don't need a `filter`. It is debatable if it is more readable, but it is shorter and saves one walk over the collection I think (although I measure no difference in performance between the `if`-statement and the `filter`). Also there is no need for parentheses around `println`:

```
(->> (range 1000)
     (reduce #(if (or (divisible-by? 5 %2)
                      (divisible-by? 3 %2))
                (+ %1 %2)
                %1))
     println)
```

You can get inspired by other answers on the [projecteuler thread for question 1](https://projecteuler.net/thread=1).